# How to fix a recording which have been sped up from the recorder using DPC speed control?

Tags: audio-recording, recording, sony, speed

In my Sony recorder I accidentally switched on DPC speed control. I recorded for more than an hour (I can't remember exactly) but the output file is about 5 minutes. It sounds like a file which have been sped up. How can I undo this?

Here's a sample file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/xsqw7nn0tth01tx/dpc.mp3?dl=0

Comment: Everything I can google about the Sony recorders says DPC is a playback tool only.

Comment: When played from the recorder it works fine.

Comment: My bet would be whatever you're loading it into for playback/conversion is misreading the file headers

Comment: @tetsujin I tried both windows media player and adobe audition :-(

Comment: Above & beyond the call of duty, but post the original file to dropbox & I'll have a look.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks a lot for your help! I just uploaded a new short recording (original file) https://www.dropbox.com/s/g20dlf4ebgl47y5/150702_004.mp3?dl=0.

Comment: @Tetsujin I just posted the question in another forum http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/372702-How-to-fix-a-recording-which-have-been-sped-up-from-the-recorder-using-DPC?p=2398037#post2398037 In there I got the same answer as you did but still got to test it. Please let me know if you have a different answer.

Comment: Does this recorder actually record in mp3? The answer on the other site is pretty comprehensive & is the way to 'fix' it if it really was recorded like that, but long-term I'd have a good shout at Sony for screwing up.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yep it's recording mp3 :-)